# Visual studio code - Folder of references

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Is there is any way to add all references from the selected folder? Its too long to add references one at a time.

Comment: Ctrl+click. Standard Windows multi-select works in the references dialog.

Comment: @KennethK. in Visual Studio Code

Comment: Oh, sorry. I completely glossed over "Code" in the title.

Comment: @KennethK. its okay

Comment: `glossed over "Code" in the title` where it dosn't belong in the first place: tags should not be repeated in the title.